# tratamento de string em pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Boa Noite Senhores, 
Tenho o seguinte Dataframe, importado de um xlsx.

```
    NUM_LEGISLACAO  DSC_URL  COD_SITUACAO  ...    DSC_TIPO     num   ano
264    89.272/1984      NaN           2.0  ...   NORMATIVO  89.272  1984
265    90.396/1984      NaN          11.0  ...   NORMATIVO  90.396  1984
266    90.804/1985      NaN           2.0  ...    CONCRETO  90.804  1985
267     81195/1978      NaN           NaN  ...         NaN   81195  1978
268      5475/1905      NaN           NaN  ...         NaN   05475  1905
269    90.396/1984      NaN          11.0  ...   NORMATIVO  90.396-A  1984
```

Importei com o código abaixo:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file01, sheet_name='Exportar Planilha')
df1['num'], df1['ano'] = df1['NUM_LEGISLACAO'].str.split('/').str

#notok
#substitui '.' e '-' no campo 'num'
df1['num'] = df1.num.str.replace('[\.-]', '')

#formata com 5 digitos
df1.num = df1.num.astype(str).str.rjust(5, '0')
df1['num'] = df1.num.astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

Pretendo retirar '.' do campo 'num', e produzir o seguinte resultado:

```
    NUM_LEGISLACAO  DSC_URL  COD_SITUACAO  ...    DSC_TIPO     num   ano
264    89.272/1984      NaN           2.0  ...   NORMATIVO  89272  1984
265    90.396/1984      NaN          11.0  ...   NORMATIVO  90396  1984
269    90.396/1984      NaN          11.0  ...   NORMATIVO  90396A  1984
```

Entretanto meu código não funciona e apresenta o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance().

Comment: Em *CSV* funciona: https://repl.it/repls/VerticalDarksalmonMicroscope

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei o motivo da falha neste post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496822/5132101.
Devido a um bug no Python 3.5.2 e anteriores, o erro acontece.

O meu ambiente é um Linux Ubuntu, que não traz update para esta versão do python, então para resolver, instalei um ambiente Anaconda, que vem com diversas versões Python disponíveis.

Detalhes em https://brito.blog.incolume.com.br/2018/06/anaconda.html